# Stop movement of a node in one simulator

Tags: java, simulation, one-simulator

How to stop movement of a particular node in [One Simulator](https://akeranen.github.io/the-one/)?
Speed settings are found in *default_settings.txt* .But how to change the speed of a node dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can also use the other movement module in movement folder. Most of them are map-based movement, if you can provide corresponding map-based data, you can achieve "move for some time and stop thereafter".

Meanwhile, writing your own movement module is an alternative method and it can be more effective in most cases. 
In ONE simulator, you need to know that the location of each node is updated in `moveHosts(double timeIncrement)` function in `World.java`. 
To realize your own movement logic, you need to rewrite `move()` function in `DTNHost.java`. A new movement module (e.g., MoveAndStop.java) which inherit `MovementModel class` in `MovementModel.java` and changes about `Group.MovementModel=MoveAndStop.java` in `default_settings.txt` are also required.

Note that if you want to realize your own movement logic according to the current simulation time, you can call `SimClock.getTime()` function to get it.

I hope my answer can inspire you to solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah.I changed MovementModel setting in default_settings.txt to "linear movement".By doing so I am able to give start and end location.Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 0):

In movement folder, there exist `"StationaryMovement"` module, which can make a particular node stay in a particular location.

Setting in `"default_settings.txt"`:
To enable this module, at first, you need to create this particular node as a single Group (e.g., `Group1`) . Then, you need to change `"movementModel"` setting of this group as `"StationaryMovement"`.

For example:

```
Group1.groupID = S
Group1.nrofHosts = 1
Group1.movementModel = StationaryMovement
Group1.nodeLocation = [X,Y]
...
...
```

Comment: Changing the setting in "Stationary Movement" makes the node stationary.But I want it to move for some time and stop thereafter.